# Optimizing each loop in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, optimization

I have a working piece of JQuery which finds a certain row in a table and then does something to it, my problem is that, sometimes, i have over 2000 pieces of data to match to a td and over 2000 rows in the table, so it can take a very long time.

(P.S Each td can only be matched once)

**JQuery**

```
$("#tableAName").on("click", "tr", function () {
    //Get Some Data
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("GetGroupRights", "Home")',
        data: { 'groupName': insertText },
        type: "post",
        cache: false,
        datatype: 'json',
        success: function (data) { <=== data RETURNS LIST OF STRING WHICH MATCH TD'S
        if (!jQuery.isEmptyObject(data)) {
            $td = $('#tableBName td');
            $.each(data.groupIDs, function (index, val) {
                $td.each(function () {
                    if ($(this).text() === val) {
                     $(this).closest(".classY").addClass(".classX")
              $(".classX").find(".classA").removeClass('classB').addClass('classC');


                  }
                });
            });
        }
    });
});
```

As I mentioned before this works perfectly fine but can be very slow, is there a way of maybe not looking at a certain row once it has been found?

Thanks and please ask if you have any questions and/or need any more info

Comment: If you used the text as a class (or some other attribute value) on each `<td>` element, you could let the browser CSS engine do the searching for you.

Comment: You can at least save about 1/2 the time by adding a `return false;` when you find a match. That'll stop the `.each()` loop from pointless subsequent iterations.

Comment: Sorry should have mentioned that the Table is created dynamically using DevExpress so cannot make changes to the structure @Pointy

Comment: Thanks will give it a try now @Pointy

Comment: See the answer I posted; something like that should be much, much faster.

Comment: Unless you've oversimplified you code, the line, `$(".classX").find(".classA").removeClass('classB').addClass('classC');` just needs to be run once, not as many times as the `if` condition is satisfied.

Comment: @PeterKA I think the deal is that the ajax response contains a whole bunch of keys that correspond to table cells that require an update. I agree that that statement should only be run once per value, and that the `.each()` should be terminated when it runs.

Comment: I have shortened the code, that line has a $(this) on the line before but took it out to shorten code @PeterKA

Comment: @hjardine, I thought as much. When you remove the context, `this`, the meaning of your question changes totally. I would suggest putting it back so the intent of your question is retained.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make a pass over the table to create a map of cell values and element references:

```
var map = {};
$("tableName td").each(function() {
  map[$(this).text()] = this;
});
```

Then your ajax callback can do this:

```
$.each(data.groupIDs, function (index, val) {
    $(map[val]).find(".classA").removeClass("classB").addClass("classC");
});
```

(If you always do a `.find()` like that in your real code, you could pre-compute that when you're making the map too.)

Comment: Would I put the 'var map = {};' section in the same JQuery code or on its own? @pointy

Comment: @hjardine well you'll want to create that map as infrequently as possible, since it requires a pass over all the cells in the table. If the table cell contents don't change, there should be no need to rebuild the map.

Comment: Wow worked perfect and saved an incredible amount of time! thanks +1 for thinking outside the box!

Answer (score 1):

You can shorten some of the time by adding the :contains filter to your td selector

```
if (!jQuery.isEmptyObject(data)) {
    $.each(data.groupIDs, function (index, val) {
        $td = $('#tableBName td:contains(val)');
        $td.each(function () {
            if ($(this).text() === val) {
                $(".classX").find(".classA").removeClass('classB').addClass('classC');
                return false;
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.filter(fn)` on `$td` to eliminate the inner loop. The method will only return `td` elements that meet the condition and you can operate on them directly. Please note that `.filter(fn)` does use `.each()` internally. Therefore, there may not be much performance improvement but your code does look more concise.

```
$td = $('#tableBName td');
$.each(data.groupIDs, function (index, val) {
    $td.filter(function() {
        return $(this).text() === val;
    })
    .closest(".classY").addClass(".classX")
    .find(".classA").removeClass('classB').addClass('classC');
});
```